# Accessing a global variable inside a namespace

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Having trouble trying to declare a variable within a var namespace ..
jsFiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/jeh7Y/

`Error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id`
`Line: 23, Column: 8
Source Code:
    var startTime = null;`

```
var Utils = {

    var startTime = null;

    getStartTime: function(){

        return startTime;
    },

    setStartTime: function(startTimeTemp){
        startTime = startTimeTemp;
    },
}

Utils.setStartTime(new Date());
alert(Utils.getStartTime());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying declare a variable in an object literal. That is not allowed.

Instead use this idiom:

```
var Utils = function(startTime) {
    this.getStartTime = function(){
        return startTime;
    };

    this.setStartTime = function(startTimeTemp){
        startTime = startTimeTemp;
    };
}
u = new Utils(new Date());
alert(u.getStartTime());
```

If javascript is not your first language it may be difficult to understand that startTime 'stays' with the instance of Utils. This is because javascript has closure. [This](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) may be worth a read.

Comment: Using js for few months now but still picking up concepts, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `startTime` as an object property as shown, then use `this` to reference the property:

```
var Utils = {

    startTime: 'test',

    getStartTime: function() {    
        return this.startTime;
    },

    setStartTime: function(startTimeTemp) {
        this.startTime = startTimeTemp;
    },
}

alert(Utils.getStartTime());    
Utils.setStartTime(new Date());
alert(Utils.getStartTime());​
```